# How Can I Define a Test Directory for Mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, babeljs, isparta

I've written my tests using ES6 and executed them (with code coverage report) as follows:

```
$> babel-node isparta cover _mocha backend/tests
```

However, the tests are not found. It only works when I have a `./test` directory.

Any suggestions on how I can define a different test directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better try to use the following syntax:

`babel-node isparta cover _mocha -- './backend/tests/*' --recursive`

Comment: I needed to include `node_modules/<module>/bin/` in order to work properly.